# Data Grid View Scoll bar issues

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have One Winform.There is one TabContainer inside it in Fill Mode I am adding one another  form with group box and DataGridView with dock mode fill as control of tab inside that tab control with dock mode fill.I have set Scroll bar property to both for DataGridView but not able to Show Horizontal.

```
 if (activeForm != null &&
        hasReviseAvgDiscountPermission == true)
    {
      //Add for in tab page.
      FrmRePricing reviseAvgDiscount = new FrmRePricing(activeForm, secondaryUser);

      if (reviseAvgDiscount.WidgetDataLoaded == true)
      {
        reviseAvgDiscount.CloseOnEscape = false;
        reviseAvgDiscount.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        reviseAvgDiscount.TopLevel = false;
        tabPgAvgDiscountRevision.Controls.Add(reviseAvgDiscount);
        reviseAvgDiscount.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        reviseAvgDiscount.Show();
        reviseAvgDiscount.Focus();
      }
      else
      {
        //Remove tab page if no data found.
        tabWidget.TabPages.Remove(tabPgAvgDiscountRevision);
      }
```

this is code to load form as control.and I have data in grid there are show many columns but show intial some columns.

Comment: Explain that more... and show us some code? Have you tried to insert some values in the datagridview?

Comment: When I open this form directly on button click as show dialog scroll bar visible